# Multiplying a list of integer with a list of string

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-manipulation

Suppose there are two lists:

```
l1 = [2,2,3]
l2 = ['a','b','c']
```

I wonder how one finds the product of the two such that the output would be:

```
#output: ['a','a','b','b','c','c','c']
```

if I do:

```
l3 = []
for i in l2:
    for j in l1:
        l3.append(i)
```

I get:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

which is wrong, I wonder where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop `for j in l1:` will iterate 3 times every time (because you have 3 items in list `l1`).

Try:

```py
out = [b for a, b in zip(l1, l2) for _ in range(a)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5):

you can (abuse) sum:

```
>>> sum([[a] * b for a, b in zip(l2, l1)], [])
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python, you an directly *multiply* a string by a number:

```
l1 = [2,2,3]
l2 = ['a','b','c']


res = [c for a, b in zip(l2, l1) for c in a * b]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

As a functional programming alternative:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import mul

res = list(chain.from_iterable(map(mul, l2, l1)))

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: `for c in a * b` only works if strings are single characters.

Answer (score 3):

If you multiply a string with an integer, it just repeats that string: e.g. `'a' * 3` outputs `'aaa'`.

So, with a list comprehension:

```py
out = [b for a, b in zip(l1, l2) for _ in range(a)]
print(out)
```

Output:

```py
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

With only 1 for loop :

```
res = []
for i in range(len(l1)): res += [l2[i]] * l1[i]
print(res)
```

Output :

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**`itertools.repeat`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to repeat the string you want:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat

>>> l1 = [2, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> [v for n, s in zip(l1, l2) for v in repeat(s, n)]
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

This works even if `l2`'s substrings are more than one character.

I like this way of doing it as it's a bit more readable (to me at least!).

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it like this :**

```
l1 = [2,2,3]
l2 = ['a','b','c']

# You can zip the two lists together then create a list by multiplying 
#their elements then converting back to a list like so :
l = [ list([s] * i) for i, s in zip(l1, l2)]
output = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
output
```

Comment: `list(s * i)` only works for single characters; better use `[s] * i`

Comment: Yes that's a more general way in case of non-single character strings.

Answer (score 0):

Hi William there are above very good answers, what i tried was to create function that will take your number list and char list and produce new list with each char added with the amount you specify in number list:

```
enter code here
l1 = [2,2,3]
l2 = ['a','b','c']

def new_list(num_list, char_list):
    l3 = []
    for i in range(0,len(num_list)):
        amount_to_append = num_list[i]
        item_to_be_added = char_list[i]
        for i in range(0,amount_to_append):
            l3.append(item_to_be_added)
    return l3
```